# Create a non-blocking timer to erase data

Tags: c, timer

Someone can show me how to create a non-blocking timer to delete data of a struct?
I've this struct:

```
struct info{
         char buf;
         int expire;
      };
```

Now, at the end of the expire's value, I need to delete data into my struct. the fact is that in the same time, my program is doing something else. so how can I create this? even avoiding use of signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work. The time it takes to delete the structure is most likely much less than the time it would take to arrange for the structure to be deleted later. The reason is that in order to delete the structure later, some structure has to be created to hold the information needed to *find* the structure later when we get around to deleting it. And then that structure itself will eventually need to be freed. For a task so small, it's not worth the overhead of dispatching.

In a difference case, where the deletion is really complicated, it may be worth it. For example, if the structure contains lists or maps that contain numerous sub-elements that must be traverse to destroy each one, then it might be worth dispatching a thread to do the deletion.

The details vary depending on what platform and threading standard you're using. But the basic idea is that somewhere you have a function that causes a thread to be tasked with running a particular chunk of code.

**Update:** Hmm, wait, a *timer*? If code is not going to access it, why not delete it now? And if code is going to access it, why are you setting the timer now? Something's fishy with your question. Don't even think of arranging to have anything deleted until everything is 100% finished with it.

Comment: the situation is particular. I've a client that ask my program to get a file. now, my program get file through a server. every files have some information, for example the expire field. then, my program get the file and send it to client. at the same time, my program save it into a kind of cache. but at the end of the expire value, I need to erase that file from cache. so, how can I implement it? this is why I need a timer, while my program handle every request from the clients. I'm under linux with gcc

Comment: Store the expire time in the cache. Then, when you happen to notice expired items in the cache, remove them. If necessary, every once in a while, call a cache expire function. (You can check inside your main activity loop how long it has been since your last expire. If more than, say, 10 seconds, do an expire.)

Comment: you wrote:" when you happen to notice expired items in the cache...." if my program is doing something else, for example is handling a request from a client, and one file in the cache is expired, how can I get advise of it? 
example: file A is into cache. A's expire = 20seconds.
client requests file B. the handling of this request takes 30 seconds. so 10 seconds ago, I should delete file A.
when?
- at the end of file B request?
- at the precise moment when file A expires?

Comment: what I mean for "cache" is a struct, used to save some functional information for expire purpose.is what you mean too?

Comment: @rschirin When you're going through the cache to find B, if you happen to notice A and it's expired, then remove it. If not, it's not doing any harm in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use signals, you're going to need threads of some kind. Any more specific answer will depend on what operating system and toolchain you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the motto is to have a timer and if it expires as in case of Client Server logic. You need to delete those entries for which the time is expired. And when a timer expires, you need to delete that data.
If it is yes: Then it can be implemented in couple of ways.
a) Single threaded : You create a sorted queue based on the difference of (interval - now ) logic. So that the shortest span should receive the callback first. You can implement the timer queue using map in C++. Now when your work is over just call the timer function to check if any expired request is there in your queue. If yes, then it would delete that data. So the prototype might look like set_timer( void (*pf)(void*));  add_timer(void * context, long time_to_expire); to add the timer.

b) Multi-threaded : add_timer logic will be same. It will access the global map and add it after taking lock. This thread will sleep(using conditional variable) for the shortest time in the map. Meanwhile if there is any addition to the timer queue, it will get a notification  from the thread which adds the data. Why it needs to sleep on conditional variable, because, it might get a timer which is having lesser interval than the minimum existing already. 
So suppose first call was for 5 secs from now
and the second timer is 3 secs from now.
So if the timer thread only sleeps and not on conditional variable, then it will wake up after 5 secs whereas it is expected to wake up after 3 secs.

Hope this clarifies your question.
Cheers,